# Как установить возможности htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Есть `php.ini,` есть `htaccess`. Во втором некоторые настройки удаётся переопределить, а некоторые нет. С чем это связано (понятно, безопасность) и, самое главное, как разрешить переопределять в `htaccess` больше настроек чем обычно?

Answer (score 0):

> как разрешить переопределять в htaccess больше настроек чем обычно?

Изменить в php.ini

см
http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/ini.list.php
http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/configuration.changes.modes.php
http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php
http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/ini.sections.php